# Can I use iOS 13+ without creating a passcode?

Tags: password

I was given a hand-me-down iPhone and I just installed the update to 13.3 and upon booting after the update it's prompting me to create a passcode. I do not see any option to skip creating a passcode as I saw previously when I first set up the phone.

Is there any way to skip creating a passcode entirely, or is it required by newer versions of iOS? Is there any way to bypass the requirement?

Screenshot. After the update I get the "Hello" screen followed by a "Software Update Complete" screen with a "Continue button" which leads to the "Create a Passcode" screen below. If I select "Passcode Options" I get only what is displayed here. The phone was factory reset last week and I never created a passcode. Tapping cancel takes me back to the "Create a Passcode" text or number entry. I can't seem to bypass this screen in any way and notifications are blocked. I assume that this is a thing in iOS 13 that now *requires* a passcode full stop, but I couldn't find any confirmation of that in my searches (everything that comes up is nonsense about bypassing a passcode if you forgot it, which is totally irrelevant).

[image]

Comment: Don't you see "passcode options" as said in https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios13-iphone-xs-setup-face-id-create-passcode.jpg  on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202033? You can set one now, turn it off later too

Comment: What precisely is the screen saying to you? Can you make a screenshot or upload a picture?

Comment: Added screenshot with some context. When I first set up the phone it gave me the option to skip creating a passcode, but I had to fiddle with it a couple times before it showed up. The phone is essentially useless at this screen, since I can't bypass it and notifications are blocked during this screen.

Comment: Are you trying to setup Touch ID ?? If so you need to have a passcode - if not setting up Touch ID, you can just turn it off in the “Touch ID & Passcode” setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel passcode options, go back (top-left button) until Touch ID setup, and don’t set up Touch ID (skip). Then when prompted for a passcode, choose Passcode Options and an option will exist for not setting a passcode.

If you can’t go back to Touch ID setup, enter a passcode to get through setup, then once the device is set up, go to Settings and disable Touch ID, then you can turn off passcode.

The text at the top of the page in your photo is different depending on whether you have enabled Touch ID or not. In this case, you have enabled Touch ID, therefore a passcode is required. If you don’t use Touch ID, you have the option for no passcode.

Comment: I'm guessing this was it - as soon as you pointed it out I smacked myself in the head for not reading the subtext. I don't know exactly how thumbprint got enabled but I am learning how hard Apple pushes you to turn things on even if I don't want them.